# Compiling issue with ifort composer_xe_2015.3.187

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran

I am compiling my Fortran code with the latest Fortran compiler composer_xe_2015.3.187 on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit system.

I am using this compiler flag:

```
-fp-model precise
```

The error message is:

> f95: error: precise: No such file or directory 
>   f95: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fp-model’

The same code does not show this error with older ifort version composerxe-2011.4.191

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On (Vanilla) Ubuntu, `f95` is a link to `gfortran` (the GNU GCC Fortran compiler), not `ifort` (Intel's Fortran compiler):

```
$ which f95 
/usr/bin/f95

$ ls -la /usr/bin/f95
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Apr 15  2014 /usr/bin/f95 -> /etc/alternatives/f95

$ ls -la /etc/alternatives/f95
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Apr 15  2014 /etc/alternatives/f95 -> /usr/bin/gfortran
```

`gfortran` does not support `-fp-model`.

You should use `ifort` instead (you probably need to edit the Makefile). Alternatively, you could change the link to point to the `ifort` binary.

Comment: So how can i do that pointing out to ifort binary safely ? thanks

Comment: @TarandeepKalra I'm no expert on Ubuntu and the alternatives system... Maybe you should ask that on http://askubuntu.com/.